# Unable to set EXECUTE permissions on users. Permission Denied when running SQL Server Agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent

I'm getting the following error when starting a SQL Server Agent Job:

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_...', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'

I can see this is a duplicate of many questions asked before, but none of those solutions are working for me...

Basically every previous question suggests granting permissions at different levels to different users and I've tried every combination I can think of. It's a local database, so I'm not too worried about granting permissions to a user who shouldn't have them as it's only me using it anyway.

```
GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE, UPDATE, INSERT ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM] WITH GRANT OPTION
```

This is what I've been doing as well as granting to PUBLIC or to my Windows user and trying to grant the permissions just on the stored procedure, then the msdb database and then the schema.

When I run my job in SQL Server Agent it fails with this error:

```
Executed as user: <COMPUTER NAME>\SYSTEM. The step failed.
Description: While trying to find a folder on SQL an OLE DB error was encountered with error code 0x80040E09 (The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_ssis_getfolder', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.).
```

Does anyone have any idea why I can't seem to grant these permissions or why with the permissions I still wouldn't be able to execute the sp_ssis_getfolder?

Comment: See here for possible solution... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/3e0b93e3-e5c8-4d63-9519-99b700b2db23/ssis-error-code-dtseoledberror-an-ole-db-error-has-occurred-error-code-0x80040e09?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: I hadn't thought about the source DB at all, was just looking at the destination DB. That's fixed it. Do you want to add that comment as an answer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Already been solved... Glad that worked!